# Value is getting empty after using jquery nice select plugin in angular

Tags: jquery, angular

I have a form select in reactive form which works fine when no external plugins use. I used jquery nice select plugin and this time i discovered that it's getting empty value. I'm newbie in angular and i really don't know what's the way of getting value after using plugin.

My form.html

```
     <select name="select" data-msg-required="Please, fill in this field" aria-required="true" formControlName="country">
                        <option value="">Country</option>
                        <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
                        <option value="JP">Japan</option>
                    </select>
```

My custom.js

```
 $('select').niceSelect();
```

My form.ts

```
this.createForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        country: ['']
    });
console.log(this.createForm.value);
```

Output:

```
{country: ""}
```

Comment: I think you should rather switch to a plugin that supports Angular. Your present plugin is having no community support as well as outdated.

Comment: Really? Is there any way with existing plugin? Or do you have any suggestion for me which plugin is better to use?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem removing the `$('select').niceSelect();` from `custom.js` and adding `class="nice-select"` in `select` tag. It will not look like a perfect nice select but will be great for you.

[Result of the change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG0BW.png)